# How to calculate sum of all nodes in a graph?

Tags: graph

I am new to DFS and while trying to do something on DFS here's a program that I tried to write myself. The idea is to calculate the sum of all nodes of the subtree rooted at node 1. 
The idea is to create a function dfs(node) such that it stores the sum of values of the nodes of its sub-tree rooted at *'node'*. When parent==child I ensured that the loop stops (otherwise there's going to be an infinite recursion).

The program fails to compile however.

Code (Ideone : https://ideone.com/ntS9AG) :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ff(i,ii,jj) for(int i=ii; i<=jj; i++)

    int n;
    int val[10000];
    vector<int> adj(10000); // adj.size() compiles correctly when adj[10000] is written; won't that create columns instead of rows?
    int sum[10000];
    bool visited[10000];

    void dfs(int node)
    {

        if (!visited[node])
        {
            sum[node]+=val[node];
            visited[node]=true;
            for (int i=0; i<adj[node].size(); i++)
            {
                if (!visited[adj[node][i]]) {visited[adj[node][i]]=true; dfs(adj[node][i]); sum[node]+=sum[adj[node][i]];}
            }
        }
    }

int main()
{
    memset(sum,0,sizeof(sum));
    memset(visited, false, sizeof(visited));
    cin>>n;
    for (int i=1; i<=n-1; i++) {int x,y; cin>>x>>y; adj[x].push_back[y]; adj[y].push_back[x];}
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) cin>>val[i];
    dfs(1);

    cout<<sum[1];
}
```

*P.S. : This program is just to write something on DFS and hence I tried doing the recursions. I am certainly aware of the fact that I could have just summed up the input values instead.*

Answer (score 0):

vector<int> v(n) creates a vector of size n. Basically you have a single vector.

However, when you write vector<int> v[n], it generates **n** vectors which is what you should do as you are trying to implement adjacency list.

Consider this graph : 
[image: Directed Garph]

So for this, your adjacency list would look like

```
0 -> 2,3  
1 -> 0  
2 -> 1  
3 -> 4  
4 -> 0
```

Clearly you can see that you need 5 vectors to store this graph using adjacency list. That is why you need to define your graph the other way. (the way you have written in the comment).